# How can I close the current database from a Form's queryOpen or postOpen event

Tags: lotus-notes

I noticed that in a Form's postOpen events, if I do

```
set ws as new notesUIWorkspace
```

the ws.CurrentDatabase is empty so I can't issue a ws.CurrentDatabase.Close

In the queryOpen event the ws.CurrentDatabase is there but then I can't issue a ws.Prompt to ask the user if they want to close the database or not.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set Continue to false and it will work.
I tried that and it worked well.

```
Sub Queryopen(Source As Notesuidocument, Mode As Integer, Isnewdoc As Variant, Continue As Variant)
    Continue = False
    Dim ws As New notesuiworkspace
    Call ws.CurrentDatabase.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dmytro but the problem is that I need to display a message to the user to see if they want to close the db or not.   And that's not possible in the QueryOpen event but will work in the PostOpen event.

In the middle of the night I woke up with the answer: Just issue a close to the document!  So in the PostOpen event I ask if they want to continue in this database or exit.  If they want to exit, I now issue a source.close and the document closes.

For the database, I do the same thing.  In the Database Script library, I put code in the PostOpen event.  There 'source' is the database.  So I do the same: issue a Source.Close and it closes the db.

Clem